# Keil : LPC1768 UART : Error: L6200E: Symbol a multiply defined (by main.o and uart.o)

Tags: arm, lpc, keil

I am learning ARM programming. I've configured uart of lpc2148 before. But there I included entire code in single file. Today I separated them in .c and .h file. But When tried to build, I got following error

```
uart.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol a multiply defined (by main.o and uart.o).
uart.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol i multiply defined (by main.o and uart.o).
Target not created
```

Below is the code
main.c

```
//main.c

#include "uart.h"

int main(void)  {

    uart_init();
    uart_tx("Hello\r\n");

    while(1)
    {
        uart_rx();
        uart_tx(a);
        uart_tx("\r\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

uart.c

```
//uart.c
#include "uart.h"

void uart_init()    {
    PINSEL0 |= (5<<0);
    U0LCR = 0X83;
    U0DLL = 97;
    U0LCR = 0X03;

}

void uart_tx(char *data)    {
    while(*data)    {
        U0THR = *data;
        while(!(U0LSR&(1<<5)));
        data++;
    }
}

void uart_rx()  {
    for(i = 0; ; i++)   {
        while(!(U0LSR&(1<<0)));
        a[i] = U0RBR;

        if(a[i] == '\r')    {
            a[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

uart.h

```
//uart.h

#ifndef UART_H
#define UART_H

#include <LPC214X.H>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char a[100];
int i;

void uart_init();
void uart_tx(char *);
void uart_rx();

#endif
```

I found some links, but none of it seems to give a solution

[link1](http://www.keil.com/forum/14904/error-l6200e-symbol-multiply-defined-compiling-adam/)

[link2](http://www.keil.com/forum/62397/uart-uart-axf-error-l6200e-symbol-nav-code-multiply/)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `a` and `i` in a header, so they're being defined in each translation unit they're compiled in. You should put them in their respective implementation files, `static` if they don't need to be shared and in the smallest scope you can.

`i` for example is used only as a loop counter in the rx function, either declare it at the top of the function or if you're using c99 then declare it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Variables 'a' and 'i' should be **declared** in uart.h using the 'extern' attribute. Variables 'a' and 'i' should be **defined** in uart.c, and only in uart.c  The declaration in uart.h tells the compiler about the characteristics of the two variables and the 'extern' attribute indicates that they are **defined** somewhere else (uart.c in this case).

The definition of the variables in uart.c should be outside of any function so that they have global scope. It's a good idea to put this definition before any functions as well.

You should use better variable names, by the way.

Comment: Ok, putting `int i`, `char a[100]` in **uart.c**  and `extern char a[100];` in **uart.h** solved the issue. But i don't understand the need of putting `extern char a[100];` in **uart.h**, since it only has function declaration and these variables are not using there. Also in **main.c**, there's a function call `uart_tx(a)`, but I've not defined the variable there so why isn't producing error. Before posting this post here, I put `extern char a[100];` in **main.c** , but it produced same error. What's the difference between putting this **main.c** and **uart.h**